# Issue updating tables with always encrypted

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I can insert new records into my tables with some columns encrypted (I use the always encrypted feature).
But... I can't update or delete rows.

Just an example: the tbUtenti table has the password column encrypted. The method works correctly in the insert, but not in the update.

The exception I got is (translation from italian language):

Cryptographic schema mismatch for columns / variables '@ p2', 'Password'. The encryption scheme for columns / variables is (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'BISP_PK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DEVDB'), while the expression next to row '1' expects it to be ( encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC') (or lower).

My method is as follows:

```
        public static bool SetUtente(tbUtenti ut){try
        {
            DBDesktopDataContext contesto = new DBDesktopDataContext(ConnectionString);
            if (ut != null)
            {
                // update
                tbUtenti utDB = contesto.tbUtentis.Where(u => u.Utente == ut.Utente).FirstOrDefault();
                if (contesto.tbUtentis.Count() > 0 && utDB != null && utDB.Utente == ut.Utente)
                { 
                    utDB.AuthFacebook = ut.AuthFacebook;
                    utDB.AuthGoogle = ut.AuthGoogle;
                    utDB.IsAdmin = ut.IsAdmin;
                    utDB.Password = ut.Password;
                    contesto.SubmitChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    // insert new row  (THIS WORKS!)
                    contesto.tbUtentis.InsertOnSubmit(ut);
                    contesto.SubmitChanges();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { ...
```